Filter a sharepoint list based on the filtering of another sharepoint list
I have a Sharepoint list called modules_list with the following columns: module of type Choice (only one value is possible in the column) and app_user of type Person. This shows which modules the app_user is assigned to.
I have another Sharepoint list called warnings_list which has the following columns: module of type Choice, status of type Choice and warning of type Text.
I also have a variable called CurrentUser which tracks the current logged in user.
I want to make a gallery that shows to the CurrentUser only the warnings for the modules that they are assigned to.
Example:

Existing modules in modules_list: Module 1, Module 2, Module 3
Assigned modules to CurrentUser: Module 1, Module 3
Warnings in warnings_list: Module 1, Module 2
Desired Outcome: a gallery in which the CurrentUser only sees the warning for Module 1 because that is the module they are assigned to.

I made a gallery and filtered modules_list to get only the modules the current user is assigned to with this code and this works:
Filter(
    modules_list,
    app_user.Email = CurrentUser.email.Email
)

How can I filter a second gallery based on the output of the first one to get the warnings only for the CurrentUser? I don't need the first gallery (the one that filters modules_list) but I do need to have a gallery that shows the warnings of the modules of CurrentUser.
